# Conditional formatting with Icon sets

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

I could not figure out the problem with this code:

```
     With .Range("K8:K" & lRow)
        Set IconCondn = .FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition

        With IconCondn.FormatConditions(1)
            .ReverseOrder = True
            .ShowIconOnly = False
            .IconSet = ActiveWorkbook.IconSets(xl3Symbols)
        End With
        With IconCondn.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(2)
            .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
            .Value = loLi
            .Operator = 7
        End With
        With IconCondn.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(3)
            .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
            .Value = upLi
            .Operator = 7
        End With
     End With
```

It is giving me an error with the third line `With IconCondn.FormatConditions(1)`.

Comment: Try using just `With IconCondn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With .Range("K8:K" & lRow)
        Set IconCondn = .FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition

        With IconCondn.IconCriteria(1)
            .ReverseOrder = True
            .ShowIconOnly = False
            .IconSet = ActiveWorkbook.IconSets(xl3Symbols)
        End With
        With IconCondn.IconCriteria(2)
            .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
            .Value = loLi
            .Operator = 7
        End With
        With IconCondn.IconCriteria(3)
            .Type = xlConditionValueNumber
            .Value = upLi
            .Operator = 7
        End With
     End With
```

I believe the addition of `.FormatConditions(1)` was the issue, that part isn't necessary.  See [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840236.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answers. it worked without .IconCriteria(1).